# Go back key in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to code the back key in android to go back to a page that continuously updates and changes. At the moment it just goes back with outs seeing the changes.

**Here is the code**

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// do something on back.
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
return;
}
```

I have also tried

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{  
    //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
    {  
        //do whatever you want the 'Back' button to do  
        //as an example the 'Back' button is set to start a new Activity named 'NewActivity'  
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }  
    return true;  
}
```

The softkey is on the right of the phone and making it with phonegap.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like horrible UX...

Comment: What are you returning to? A Fragment? An Activity? Is the problem that whatever it is in the backstack, so you're getting a stale view of it? Not quite following.

Comment: A web content of the previous state it shows

Answer (score 0):

Try to give some random data (or System.currentTimeMillis()) to the end of the url :-) - after question-mark:

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html?hgjhfsd
```

Or try:

```
super.clearCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using javascript. Add an event listener

Add a listner

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown()
{
     window.location="index.html";
}
```